# (Java) How Do I Sort Numbers From Least to Greatest and Assign Them to Variables?

Tags: java, sorting

I have a homework assignment that asks me to create a program that takes three sides of a triangle input in any order, sorts them from least to greatest, and then determines if it is a valid triangle, what the area is, and what type of triangle it is. I have all my methods figured out, but I can't figure out how to sort my inputs from least to greatest, which is how I need my inputs to be sorted so my method "triangleType" functions correctly.

I've scoured Stack Overflow and found a few different sorting solutions, but often in different languages or not explaining how to set the sort of an array to specific variables. I want sideA to be the smallest and sideC to be the largest.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);        
        double sideA, sideB, sideC;
        System.out.println("Enter the side lengths of the triangle: ");
        sideA = kbd.nextDouble();
        sideB = kbd.nextDouble();
        sideC = kbd.nextDouble();



        if(MyTriangleBenAlyk.isValid(sideA, sideB, sideC) == true)
        {           
            double area = MyTriangleBenAlyk.area(sideA, sideB, sideC);            
            String type = MyTriangleBenAlyk.triangleType(sideA, sideB, sideC);
            System.out.println("The triangle type is: " + type + "\n"
                    + "The area is: " + area);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Triangle");
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Easiest idea would be storing the values in a data structure that sorts it automatically, e.g. a `TreeSet<Double>`. As an alternative, you can use a simple array (`int[]`) and implement the sorting yourself, which will be a lot harder but you will learn a lot more. You may learn that later on in your course, so I would stick to the easy things for now.

Comment: In what universe sorting is "a lot hard"?

Comment: Ashvin, I'm new to coding. Thanks for the helpful input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO. I suggest that instead of using individual variables you use an array and then use `Arrays.sort` to order them:

```
double[] sides = new double[3];
sides[0] = kbd.nextDouble();
...
Arrays.sort(sides);
```

Comment: Thanks! This proved to be the best solution. I ended up taking the inputs and setting them to new variables:

`double[] sort = {inputA, inputB, inputC};
Arrays.sort(sort);
double sideA = sort[0];
double sideB = sort[1];
double sideB = sort[2];`